# Why does Wolfram|Alpha give inconsistent result for $\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{x-x^2}-e^{-x-x^2}}{x}~dx$?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, complex, wolfram-alpha-queries

Why Wolfram gives inconsistent result for :

$$I=\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{x-x^2}-e^{-x-x^2}}{x}~dx$$

As shown in the picture below, the analytical integration gives $-i\pi$, but numerical integration gives $1.93193$. The result must be a real number, but why Wolfram gives a complex result for the analytical integration?

What I suspect is Wolfram might treat this integral as Frullani integral, where $f(x)=e^{x-x^2}$, and $f(-x)=e^{-x-x^2}$. We get


$$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{x-x^2}-e^{-x-x^2}}{x}~dx=\int_0^\infty \frac{f(x)-f(-x)}{x}~dx=(f(\infty)-f(0))\ln\left(\frac1{-1}\right)=-i\pi$$
But this is WRONG!

Update: I use Mathematica 10.0 and [Wolfram Alpha online](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate%20%28e%5E%28x-x%5E2%29-e%5E%28-x-x%5E2%29%29%2Fx%2C%20x%20from%200%20to%20infinity), and both of them give the complex result.


[image]
[image]

Comment: With version `"13.3.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (June 3, 2023)"` Mathematica returns `\[Pi] Erfi[1/2]`, i.e., `1.93193` Please edit your question to indicate version/OS that you are using.

Comment: Yes, I have updated my post. I tried Mathematica 10.0 and Wolfram alpha online https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+%28e%5E%28x-x%5E2%29-e%5E%28-x-x%5E2%29%29%2Fx%2C+x+from+0+to+infinity

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I only see screenshots, no actual code

Comment: @MathFail Wolfram Alpha site uses old Mathematica 12.

Comment: Mathematica v12.2 needs a little bit assistance: `Integrate[Exp[ -x^2] /x  2 Sinh[x], {x, 0, Infinity} ]` to get the right solution `  (*\[Pi] Erfi[1/2]*)`

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Not sure why the answer is different but using V13.3 the results are consistent.

Comment: Thank you! The Wolfram alpha online gives the complex result too. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+%28e%5E%28x-x%5E2%29-e%5E%28-x-x%5E2%29%29%2Fx%2C+x+from+0+to+infinity

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, especially screenshots taken at the lowest possible resolution.